# Only show first entity reference in views

Tags: views, entities

In my situation :
I have 2 content types **content type A and B**
In **content type B** add entity reference field of **content type A**
In views, I want to display some values of **content type A**,but I also want to show some values of the first **content Type B** which has entity reference field to **content type A**.
How can i show only its first value ?

edit:
**Content Type B** has an entity reference field to **Content Type A**.
In the view I list all of the nodes of **Content Type A**.
But I also want to show some field of the first node that is referenced in **Content Type B**.

For example:
**Content Type A** has fields: title and logo.
**Content Type B** has fields: body and entity reference to **Content Type A**.
Multiple entities of **Content Type B** can be referenced to an entity of **Content Type A**.

What I want to show is:
**Content Type A** - Title
**Content Type A** - Logo
**Content Type B**[0] - Body

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can do it using global php field

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Adi, but I still don't know how.

Comment: install global php field module then select field in field section in view

Comment: But what do I have to put in the global php field?

Comment: @Jelle Mattez What do you mean by _but I also want to show some values of the first content Type B which has entity reference field to content type A._

Comment: Dammit, someone made edits to my post. well:

Comment: Content Type B has an entity reference field to content type A.
In the view I list all of the nodes of content type A.
But I also want to show some field of the first node that is referenced in content type B.

For example:
Content Type A has fields: title and logo.
Content Type B has fields: body and entity reference to Content Type A.
Multiple entities of Content Type B can be referenced to an entity of Content Type A.
What I want to show is:
Content Type A - Title
Content Type A - Logo
Content Type B[0] - Body

Comment: I made edits to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it :

1. In Views, under **Advanced**, add **Entity Reference:Referencing entity** relationship via your reference field id.
2. In Views, under fields add the field(in this case - Body) and add the above relationship .

**Note**: *If there are nodes of content type B that reference same nodes of content type A, those same nodes of content type A will be duplicated in the views with different values of the fields of content type B that is referencing them*.

**Update**: To remove such duplicates, you can use **Views Distinct** module and then in Views under fields, select Title field(Content Type A) and under **Views Distinct Settings**, change to **'Filter Repeats'** for **Filter/Aggregate this field** and save.

Comment: Well, that's the problem: your **Note**. I don't want A to be duplicated. :)

Comment: Well i guessed so..You can use [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) and then in views under fields, select Title field(Content Type A) and under Views Distinct Settings, change to 'Filter Repeats' for Filter/Aggregate this field and save.